# Shopify: How can I limit a product to 1 per customer

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

I need to limit some product to 1 per customer. We are going to have something like deal and day and targeting consumers. We do not want some one to buy high quantities. Could some one guide me as to what the general approach should be to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Authorization and Authentication with you can see the [overview][1] documentation.

Find a way to use sales record as  constraints, and then limit the total sellable product. But shopify is too rigid.


  [1]: https://shopify.dev/apps/auth

Answer (score 0):

The cheap and easy way to kill off those is to listen for the checkout click on the cart. You can analyze the cart, and ensure the quantity is 1. Unfortunately, a lot of customers will get to checkout and you'll miss that, so you could use scripting and Plus to ensure 1 == 1 == 1 for that product. If you cannot afford Plus, refund any $ for quantity > 1 on an order, and just fulfill a quantity of 1.